# How to make female's stocking as tight fit

Tags: modeling

I would like to make tightly fit stocking on female's legs but just like fisherman's boots right now...

[image: Stocking is larger than leg.]

Those stockings have slight thickness so it won't shrink(Alt + S) properly. There are small faces on the edge of stockings.

[image: There are small faces on the edge of stockings.]

I tried to resize one by one because not huge polys but don't know how to snap to legs... Each corner of stocking have four to five edges. How can I move them as group then snap to nearest leg???

Please throw your thoughts any small ideas could be solutions.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using snapping and setting it to face?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice! I tried snap function but too many options and not quite sure what should I do with the function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get the one mesh to snap to the other is to use Blenders snapping tools. The controls for this are located at the bottom of the 3D view on the right side of the row of icons just before the OpenGL render buttons.

There is a magnet icon, a small menu with a few options, and then numerous other options based on your menu choice. You will want to set the menu to face instead of increment. All of the other settings should be fine.

Now, when you select a section of your mesh and move it, if you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you move it it will snap to whatever face from another object is under your mouse. The little magnet icon can be clicked to automatically snap without holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> if that is easier for you. Snapping also works when you move something on a single axis only or two axes. I your case you may want to try pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> while moving the vertices so that you don't mess up the vertical placement while snapping.

Comment: Note that taking solidified geometry into account snapping should be done carefully to not snap outer part to inner part or making it partially sunk into the mesh to snap to (legs in this case). One workaround is removing solidified geometry

Comment: That is a good point. However if a vertical section of the top band is selected (both outer and inner geometry) and snapping used it won't go through the leg.